# can't see type 'content taxonomy list' in node import

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, content-type, drupal-taxonomy

I created a new content type 'Student'. I created a new field and chose "content taxonomy list" for "select a field type". The taxonomy is selected in the following step, this taxonomy is created in "admin/content/taxonomy" with 3 terms in it.

When i use "node_import" I can't see the created field with type 'content taxonomy list', all other fields as type 'text' are visible but not the field(s) with type 'content taxonomy list'. I looked at "admin/user/permissions" and there is only one view and one edit checkbox not selected for this 'content taxonomy list' I created for content type 'Student'. I have admin rights, what can be the reason? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give more details so that we can spot the problem.

In the mean time, you may try

- See if the "content_taxonomy module" is enabled in the new environment.
- See if the vocabulary that you selected in the content type is getting created in the new environment.
- If the above two are functioning well, then go to your content type, select the field and see if it is getting populated properly with the correct vocabulary.